# Batch inserts using ContinueOnError

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the following code to do a batch insert using the C# driver.  I have a unique index, and I want it to fail silently if I try to insert a record that isn't unique.

Even though I have `InsertFlags.ContinueOnError` set, I still get an error on the `InsertBatch` call.  If I swallow the error as I have shown below, everything works ok.  But this certainly feels wrong.

```
var mio = new MongoInsertOptions {Flags = InsertFlags.ContinueOnError};
// newImages is a list of POCO objects
try
{
    _db.GetCollection("Images").InsertBatch(newImages, mio);
}
catch (WriteConcernException)
{           
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your POCO declaration. The exception can be thrown at the driver stage (ie if one of your objects doesn't serialize) and your `WriteConcern` of `ContinueOnError` will only respected later, once the bulk insert request reaches mongo database itself. You could also try iterating over your images one at a time and seeing if one fails as an insert.

Comment: Also, what version of the csharp driver are you using? I see this bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-674 which could cause serialization to fail on your objects if they have null values, which could trigger a driver exception before reaching the db.

Comment: I'm performing a very simple experiment.  I batch insert a set of POCO objects that each have a GUID.  The collection has a unique index on that GUID.  The first insert goes fine.  I try to batch insert the exact same set of POCOs again, and I get the exception.  I expect it to ignore the inserts and not raise the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version 1.8 of the csharp Mongo driver?

If so, try upgrading to version 1.8.1 which contains a fix for the following two issues:

- [InsertBatch fails when large batch has to be split into smaller sub batches](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-715)
- [InsertBatch throws duplicate key exception with too much data...](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-725)

So your inserts could succeed, but the driver is still throwing an exception on bulk insert operations due to the bug above.

And this exception doesn't originate from the database itself, explaining why the inserts succeed but you still need to catch the exception afterwards - i.e. the db is in fact respecting your ContinueOnError flag but the driver throws an exception anyway afterwards.